# How to upgrade tomcat8 server on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, tomcat

I'm running `ubuntu xenial 16.04`. Running `aptitude install tomcat8` results in a tomcat version of `8.0.32`.

But the current release is `8.0.46`. How can I force an aptitude install or upgrade with exactly this version? `aptitude versions tomcat8` only shows the 8.0.32 versions.

I'd like to keep my existing configurations and apps from v32, but would like to upgrade to v46. But how?

Comment: I don't completely understand the question. "only shows the x.32 versions" What does that mean? Can you post the result of `aptitude versions tomcat8`, or better `apt-cache policy tomcat8`? Also, does ` v32` and `v46` correspond to the last two digits in the version number? That seems likely.

Comment: Ah, by "only shows the x.32 versions" you presumably mean `8.0.32`. The plural, versions, threw me for a moment. You don't say why you want `.46`, but you can probably backport it from a later release.

Comment: Yes. sorry. Edited above to make it more clear.

Comment: @Faheem unfortunately backports aren’t really an option here, later releases of Ubuntu have .38, not .46, and Debian moved to Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: @StephenKitt I see. In any case, I'm not sure of (and the poster doesn't state) reasons for preferring `8.0.46` over `8.0.32`.

Comment: Well, the versions are just an example of my current case. But the question is more about *how* to properly upgrade, not *when*.

Comment: @membersound it really boils down to “trust the distribution”, in most cases. If you *really* need more recent versions than what your distribution provides, you’re on your own.

Answer (score 3):

In a given Ubuntu release, software typically doesn’t get upgraded to newer upstream versions, it only gets security patches and fixes for serious bugs. In Tomcat’s case, Ubuntu 16.04 has 8.0.32 plus a number of security fixes (see [the package page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat8) for details). So running 8.0.32 is still safe.

If you *really* need to upgrade to 8.0.46 (and I don’t think there’s much reason you would, given the above), you’ll need to build it yourself.